# Four points in space, satisfying the conditions

Tags: proof-writing, vectors, euclidean-geometry, 3d, solid-geometry

> $A, B, C, D$ are four points in the space and satisfy $\mid \overrightarrow{AB} \mid = 3, \mid \overrightarrow{BC} \mid=7,\mid \overrightarrow{CD} \mid=11$ and $\mid \overrightarrow{DA} \mid=9$. Then $ \overrightarrow{AC}. \overrightarrow{BD}$ is

I know that $\overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{BC} +\overrightarrow{CA} +\overrightarrow{AD}=0$ and also I observed that $\mid \overrightarrow{AB} \mid^2+\mid \overrightarrow{CD} \mid^2=\mid \overrightarrow{BC} \mid^2+\mid \overrightarrow{DA} \mid^2$. But couldn't get anything from it. Any hint?

Comment: I find $| \overrightarrow{AC}|.| \overrightarrow{BD} |$ rather peculiar notation.
If you intend the product of $| \overrightarrow{AC}|$ and $| \overrightarrow{BD} |$
then why not just write $| \overrightarrow{AC}|| \overrightarrow{BD} |$?
I now wonder whether it's a misprint for the scalar product $\overrightarrow{AC}\cdot\overrightarrow{BD} $

Comment: You should use | rather than \mid here.

Comment: @AnginaSeng, sry edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\vec{AC}\cdot\vec{BD}=(-\vec{DA}+\vec{DC})\cdot(-\vec{DB})=\vec{DA}\cdot\vec{DB}-\vec{DC}\cdot\vec{DB}=$$
$$=DA\cdot DB\cos\measuredangle ADB-DC\cdot DB\cos\measuredangle CDB=$$
$$=\frac{9^2+DB^2-3^2}{2}-\frac{11^2+DB^2-7^2}{2}=0.$$

Comment: Wow! Grrrreaatt...